# Escape characters in a path

Tags: c#, escaping, command-line-arguments

I have a little problem with the escape characters. I made a little program that receives various arguments when started from a command line. But the problem is, that these arguments may contain a backslash, and it generates problems. Let me show you

Let's say I start my program like this:

```
C:\Program\program.exe "C:\Program\" "build and test"
```

The first parameter is the path, and the second parameter would be a command the program should interpret (in this case, it should 'build and test' something)

The problem is, that if I print out the arguments, I get this:

```
C:\Program" build
and
test
```

While what I would need is:

```
C:\Program\
build and test
```

I know that \" is ruining everything there, so what kind of action should i take:

- Implement a method to format/replace the escape characters (if possible)
- Teach people inserting paths as arguments in an appropriate way (with a forward slash, or without a slash in the end at all)
- Delete the last backslash somehow
- Something else?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Given that you only get the individual arguments, you cannot really repair this afterwards. So the correct approach would be to fix the input, i.e. either keep the backslash off, or don’t escape the path at all when there’s no space inside. You should use your console’s tab completion there; it will automatically enquote paths as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the \ by adding \\  or @"PATH" - Verbatim String Literal